# Sorting on four columns

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have the following sheet and code which at the moment are not working as it should be. What I want is to sort

1. First column F,
2. Then column B,
3. Then column D,
4. and last column E

The data in column A:F is a dataset and therefore I need to make the above sorting (F, B, D, E) for the whole dataset and not just taking one column after each other.

Also, I have some data above in row 1 so I can't just take "whole" columns but need to sort in the specific "data field".

Please advice how I can add the fourth sorting so the above ranking is applied.

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Remove_Dubs_IndBB()

Dim i As Long
Dim data As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

data = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Count

Call Sum_IF
SendKeys ("{ESC}")

 With Range("A2", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

 .Sort Key1:=Cells(1, 6), Order1:=xlDescending, _
 Header:=xlNo

    For i = 1 To data
        If (VBA.Date - Cells(i, 4)) / 365 > 5 Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).ClearContents
        End If
        If (Cells(i, 5) - VBA.Date) / 365 < 1.25 Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).ClearContents
        End If
     Next i

Range("A2", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address).Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Columns(6), Order1:=xlDescending, _
    Header:=xlNo

    Selection.Sort Key1:=Columns(2), Order1:=xlDescending _
    , Key2:=Columns(4), Order2:=xlDescending _
    , Key3:=Columns(5), Order3:=xlDescending _
    , Header:=xlNo


Range("A2", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates (3),        Header:=xlNo

 End With

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

 End Sub

 Sub Sum_IF()

 Dim i As Long
 Dim data As Integer

data = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Count

 With Range("A2", Range("F" & data))
 For i = 1 To data
    .Cells(i, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R2C3:R[" & data & "]C3, RC[-3], R2C2:R[" & data & "]C2)"
    .Cells(i, 6).Copy
    .Cells(i, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next i
 End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: A round about solution would be to use autofilters. You could sort the data on column F then loop through unique values in F (Hide other values using the autofilter) then sort visible data by the three other columns. This is a somewhat arduous approach though.

Comment: Hi Marc_S. Any idea how to apply the autofiler for my code?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so an answer is to sort by Column F then for ranges in F that all have the same value, sort the data by the three remaining criteria.

The following Sub will sort the data across the four columns

```
Sub SortFourCols()
    Dim RowCounter As Long, RowDepth As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim DataRows As Long: DataRows = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Count
    Dim MatchRange As Range

    ' F,B,D,E
    With ws.Sort
        .Header = xlNo
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F:F"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(DataRows, 6))
        .Apply
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D:D"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E:E"), Order:=xlAscending
    End With
    Set MatchRange = ws.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(DataRows, 6))
    With ws
        For i = 2 To DataRows
            RowDepth = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MatchRange, .Cells(i, 6).Value)
            If RowDepth > 1 Then
                With .Sort
                    .SetRange Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + RowDepth - 1, 6))
                    .Apply
                End With
            End If
            i = i + RowDepth - 1
            If i > DataRows Then Exit For
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

********* EDIT *********

Apparently, you can use more than 3 keys (the difference may be with using a range sort vs setting the worksheet sort options and using them on a range). I don't know if the version of Office makes a difference for this; but it simplifies things a great deal:

```
Sub SortFourCols()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim DataRows As Long: DataRows = ws.Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Count

    ' F,B,D,E
    With ws.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SetRange Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(DataRows, 6))
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F:F"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D:D"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E:E"), Order:=xlAscending
        .Apply
        .SortFields.Clear
    End With
End Sub
```